# can't play mp3 file via javafx 2.2 media player

Tags: javafx, mp3

I'm developing what I thought should ahve been a simple task with javafx- media player that will play mp3 files stored on the local hard drive, in users default music folder path (using fedora). I can play all the mp3 files fine from the command line, but when I try and play via javafx.scene.media libraries, javafx keeps telling me that mp3 is an upsupported media type. I've downloaded about every library I could find, but to no avail. Here is a the code that actually tries to open the file and play the media:

First attempt:

```
 public void playTrack( String audioFileName ) {
    System.out.println("going to play the file "+audioFileName);
    String filename = System.getProperty("user.home")+"/"+audioFileName;
    File audioFile = new File( filename);
    Media audioFileStream= null;
    try {
        audioFileStream = new Media(audioFile.toURI().toURL().toString());
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(audioFileStream);
    mediaPlayer.play();
}
```

Method 2:

```
public void playTrack( String audioFileName ) {
    System.out.println("going to play the file "+audioFileName);
    String source = new File(System.getProperty("user.home")+"/"+audioFileName).toURI().toString();
    //String source = new File("07-Basket-Case.mp3").toURI().toString();
    System.out.println("going to play "+source);
    Media media = null;
    media = new Media(source);
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(media);
    mediaPlayer.play();
}
```

Both produce the exact same error result, shown here:

going to play file:/home/cpeddie/workspace/parnassusfx/07-Basket-Case.mp3
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" MediaException: MEDIA_UNSUPPORTED : com.sun.media.jfxmedia.MediaException: "Error media audio format unsupported" : com.sun.media.jfxmedia.MediaException: "Error media audio format unsupported"
    at javafx.scene.media.MediaException.exceptionToMediaException(MediaException.java:125)
    at javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer.init(MediaPlayer.java:474)
    at javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer.(MediaPlayer.java:383)
    at com.promptu.parnassusfx.sample.music.MusicController.playTrack(MusicController.java:218)
    at com.promptu.parnassusfx.sample.music.MusicController$3$1$1.handle(MusicController.java:357)
    at com.promptu.parnassusfx.sample.music.MusicController$3$1$1.handle(MusicController.java:1)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:69)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:217)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:170)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:38)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:37)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:35)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:35)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:35)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:35)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:35)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:35)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:35)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:35)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:53)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:28)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:171)
    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:6867)
    at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:179)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:193)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.SkinBase$4.handle(SkinBase.java:336)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.SkinBase$4.handle(SkinBase.java:329)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:64)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:217)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:170)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:38)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:37)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:35)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:35)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:35)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:35)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:35)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:35)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:35)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:35)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:35)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:53)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:33)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:171)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3311)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3151)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1900(Scene.java:3106)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1563)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2248)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:250)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:173)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:292)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:530)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:924)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication$3$1.run(GtkApplication.java:89)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: com.sun.media.jfxmedia.MediaException: "Error media audio format unsupported"
    at com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.MediaUtils.nativeError(MediaUtils.java:331)
    at com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.platform.gstreamer.GSTMedia.init(GSTMedia.java:50)
    at com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.platform.gstreamer.GSTMedia.(GSTMedia.java:33)
    at com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.platform.gstreamer.GSTMediaPlayer.(GSTMediaPlayer.java:39)
    at com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.platform.gstreamer.GSTPlatform.prerollMediaPlayer(GSTPlatform.java:100)
    at com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.platform.PlatformManager.createMediaPlayer(PlatformManager.java:173)
    at com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.NativeMediaManager.getPlayer(NativeMediaManager.java:260)
    at com.sun.media.jfxmedia.MediaManager.getPlayer(MediaManager.java:139)
    at javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer.init(MediaPlayer.java:431)
    ... 75 more

I should also mention that I'm developing this using VMWare fusion running on a MacBook Pro with OS 10.8.5. Running Fedora 19.

Any help will be appreaciated!

Answer (score 3):

Took about a day and a half to figure it out, but needed to install the following packages:

dirac-libs-1.0.2-9.fc18.i686.rpm

libavcodec52-0.7.15-32.fc18.i686.rpm

libavformat52-0.7.15-32.fc18.i686.rpm

libavutil50-0.7.15-32.fc18.i686.rpm

libxavs1-0.1.51-2.fc18.i686.rpm

Once these were installed, javafx plays music like a charm.

Comment: where can I install these package from? I took a week still cannot find out the solution...